# Apache Time out directive

Tags: linux, apache, timeout, webserver

I set the Time out directive in Apache configuration file to a high value, i just wanna know, What are the disadvantages or the consequences of increasing the value (1800 s for exemple) of timeout in web-servers (Apache 2)?

Comment: Did you try to read [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#timeout)?

Comment: I think this question is out of the scope of SO, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic